# Ion-List 'underlapping' ion-tabs and ion-nav

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework

In my home page i have a ion-list, sometime(yes, not every time), when i select a object in this list or go to the register page, through the "this.app.getRootNav().push("ClienteCadastroPage")", and select a input in registerPage ou descriptionPage, and use "this.navCtrl.pop();" to comeback, my ion-list is under the Ion-Tab and Ion-nav

1- Ion-List: [image]

2 - After i select a item, i touch in any input
[image]

3- After i select to comeback or save
[image]

As you can see in the last pic the ion-list is under the other elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just need to resize the component when the page is loaded on the method `ionViewDidEnter()`:

Code:

```
@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

ionViewDidEnter() {
  Utils.closeMenus(this.menuCtrl);
  this.update();
}

update(){    
  this.content.resize();
}
```